# How to pass values from jar file to a Perl script

Tags: java, perl, jar

I'm trying to pass the arguments from a jar file(samplecode.jar) to a Perl script using

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("perl", "C:\\Xampp\\perl\\bin\\echocopy.pl", "10");
```

and in Perl file retrieving the value and passing the value to a jar file(Monitor.jar).The Perl code is

```
while(my $accNo = <STDIN>){
    if(length($accNo) > 1){

        $accNo = substr $accNo, 0 , (length($accNo) - 1);
        print "value received is $accNo";

        my $cmd = "";
        my $res = "";

        $cmd = "java -jar C:\Newfolder1\Monitor.jar \"$accNo\"";
        print "Execution Success";
        $res = qx/$cmd/;

        print "$res\n";



    } else {
        printf "1\n";
    }

}
```

The Monitor.jar code is

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Verifys {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String n = args[0];
            System.out.printf("the received value is:\n", n);
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Newfolder1\\filename1.txt");
            myWriter.write(n);
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not Successfully wrote to the file.");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

and in Monitor.jar I'm trying to receive that value and store it in a file but I'm unable to do it.Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: `<STDIN>` is the file handle for, well, the standard input. You won't get arguments from that. Arguments can be accessed via the `@ARGV` array.

Answer (score 1):

Command-line arguments are found in `@ARGV`.

```perl
@ARGV == 1
   or die("usage: $0 <accNo>\n");

my ($accNo) = @ARGV;
```

---

Fixes for a number of issues:

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my @cmd = ( "java", "-jar", "C:\\Newfolder1\\Monitor.jar", $accNo );
my $cmd = shell_quote(@cmd);
my $result = `$cmd`;
die("Can't execute Monitor: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("Monitor killed by signal ".( $? && 0x7F )."\n") if $? && 0x7F;
die("Monitor exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
print("Monitor executed successfully.\n");

print($result);
```

Better yet, avoid the shell:

```perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @cmd = ( "java", "-jar", "C:\\Newfolder1\\Monitor.jar", $accNo );
my $result = capturex(@cmd);
print("Monitor executed successfully.\n");

print($result);
```

---

Of course, if you're really just going to output what you captured, why capture it at all?

```
my @cmd = ( "java", "-jar", "C:\\Newfolder1\\Monitor.jar", $accNo );
system( { $cmd[0] } @cmd );
die("Can't execute Monitor: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("Monitor killed by signal ".( $? && 0x7F )."\n") if $? && 0x7F;
die("Monitor exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
print("Monitor executed successfully.\n");
```

or

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( systemx );

my @cmd = ( "java", "-jar", "C:\\Newfolder1\\Monitor.jar", $accNo );
systemx(@cmd);
print("Monitor executed successfully.\n");
```

Comment: Whatever you print out will end up in $res

Comment: No I'm trying to return the value from jar

Comment: Whatever you print from the code in the jar will end up in `$res`